# Is bankroll in PLO as important as in NLH?

Tags: omaha, bankroll-management

Bankroll is important in NLH to figth against variance.

However, at Omaha game you play with defined EVS for nut or semi-nut projects. If I put all my stack 5 times with a 17-cards straigth draw on Flop, the probability the straigth doesn't appear at any of the 5 hands where you putted many chips is very low.

That does mean bankroll is not so important at PLO, or it is as at NLH?

Comment: It's even more important and needs to be bigger because the swings are much bigger. You're not going to have a 17 card draw every time you put your money in. You're going to run very badly at some points in PLO, the equities run closer together and you'll be sucked out on more often than in holdem.

Comment: I think the pot-limit aspect of PLO might be more significant when considering the importance of bankroll. This makes it less (not much but still) likely that you will be able to get all in if you make a hand. I'm interested to know as well

Comment: @Jonast92 I come from finish reading a book where they say you are rigth and PLO needs even a bigger bankroll than NLH

Answer (score 1):

Acording to Jeff Hwang the bankroll needed for PLO is a bit bigger than for NLH:

> While pot-limit Omaha can be an exceptionally profitable game, the
>   fact that you will probably need a bigger bankroll to suppor playing
>   PLO vs NL hold'em is  in itself a cost.

---

[Jeff Hwang: "Pot-limit Omaha Poker: The big play strategy"](https://books.google.es/books?id=IfYn3HrWE4sC&printsec=frontcover&dq=Jeff%20Hwang:%20%22Pot-limit%20Omaha%20Poker:%20The%20big%20play%20strategy%22&hl=es&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwihw4eCgernAhVH-YUKHSosAwMQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=Jeff%20Hwang%3A%20%22Pot-limit%20Omaha%20Poker%3A%20The%20big%20play%20strategy%22&f=false)